# roscore on python2.7 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe6 in position 16

Tags: ros, ros-kinetic, python3

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hey,
When I set python3.5 as default, I got a error. So, I corrected it to python2.7, However, roscore gave me a Error like this

### ~$ roscore

```
... logging to /home/wuxueming/.ros/log/67c4edca-e9fb-11e8-a50a-7c2a314f2b58/roslaunch-wuxueming-n8xejek-28640.log
Checking log directory for disk usage. This may take awhile.
Press Ctrl-C to interrupt
Done checking log file disk usage. Usage is <1GB.

started roslaunch server http://wuxueming-n8xejek:37377/
ros_comm version 1.12.14


SUMMARY
========

PARAMETERS
 * /rosdistro: kinetic
 * /rosversion: 1.12.14

NODES

auto-starting new master
process[master]: started with pid [28650]
ROS_MASTER_URI=http://wuxueming-n8xejek:11311/

setting /run_id to 67c4edca-e9fb-11e8-a50a-7c2a314f2b58
'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe6 in position 16: ordinal not in range(128)
The traceback for the exception was written to the log file
[master] killing on exit
```

***'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe6 in position 16: ordinal not in range(128)***

How to solve the problem? Thanks so much.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/308745/roscore-on-python2.7-%27ascii%27-codec-can%27t-decode-byte-0xe6-in-position-16/) by [snowman](https://answers.ros.org/users/37326/snowman/) on ROS Answers with karma: 16 on 2018-11-16

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-11-16**:
Please update your post with the *full error message* / stack trace.

Never paraphrase errors or warnings.

**Comment by [snowman](https://answers.ros.org/users/37326/snowman/) on 2018-11-16**:
Thanks.And I will update with the full errror message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

**Sorry for later. A long time ago, I had saved this problem .**

It just need to open terminal and input this

```
$ sudo update-alternatives --config python
有 2 个候选项可用于替换 python (提供 /usr/bin/python)。

  选择       路径            优先级  状态
------------------------------------------------------------
  0            /usr/bin/python3   150       自动模式
* 1            /usr/bin/python2   100       手动模式
  2            /usr/bin/python3   150       手动模式
要维持当前值[*]请按<回车键>，或者键入选择的编号：
```

Next you need to chose `python2,` just it looks like, push the number `2` & `Enter`. Everything is OK.

---

Originally posted by [snowman](https://answers.ros.org/users/37326/snowman/) with karma: 16 on 2020-01-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0